# Regex. How to repalce all patterns except one?

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regular expressions, therefore I need some help.

I have a string. For example:

> "Some words <img src="www.test.com">. Next words <a href="www.abc.com">abc</a>"

I want to delete all tags except <a></a>.
Can I create one regex or I should to make several regular expression?

Expected output:

> "Some words. Next words <a href="www.abc.com">abc</a>"

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex. Use an HTML parser. Also do you really mean [tag:pyth], or [tag:python]?

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and yes, a single regexp will work.

Comment: Manipulating HTML with regular expressions is usually not a good idea. Google zalgo chtulhu html.

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: Maybe checkout [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: @displayname I choose it already, thanks.

Comment: @ShoshinNikita Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you [shouldn't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3103891), this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/xxvhBO/1) will capture all the non-`<a>` tags:

```
<\/?[^a\/].*?>
```